# Why the stuffed animals used by Yayoi to contain spirits, explode with blood when they are devoured by others spirits, if they are spirits?

Tags: dark-gathering

Yayoi uses stuffed animals to trap spirits. Then, when they fought among them, her room was splashed with a lot of blood. But they are spirits, so they arent supposed to have blood. Does the stuffed animals she uses have something else inside that makes them explode with blood, or is it that in that story, spirits when devoured by other spirits explode with blood somehow?